# Click using Xpath is not working when called from a function in puppeteer

Tags: typescript, puppeteer, jest-puppeteer

Trying to click on an element using $x but throws error.
Tried different ways but no luck, can anyone let me know what is the mistake with the below code or 
any other way to click using xpath.

```
 Error: Protocol error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Target closed.
```

below is the code

> //commonfunction.ts

```
module.exports = {};

module.exports.ToggleButton = async function ToggleButton(Question, QuestionLabelXpath) {
      await page.waitForXPath(QuestionLabelXpath + "/descendant::label[text()='" + Question + "']/parent::div/descendant::button[@title='Edit']");
      const editIcon = await page.$x(QuestionLabelXpath + "/descendant::label[text()='" + Question + "']/parent::div/descendant::button[@title='Edit']");
      await editIcon[0].click();};
```

> //questions.ts

```
const CommFun = require('./commonfunction');
    test('Verify "question"',async() => {
    CommFun.ToggleButton("question","//div[@role=\'tabpanel\']/div/div/div/div/div")
    },30000);
```

Tried $$eval within the test the click is working but when i put it in the function it is not working, does it has to do anything with the function call ?

```
const CommFun = require('./commonfunction');
test('Verify "question"',async() => {
await page.$$eval('button[title=\'Edit\']', elements => elements[1].click());
},30000);
```

Comment: Are you adding `await browser.close()` or `await page.close()` at the end of your code?

Comment: @EdiImanto i am using afterAll(()=>{
 browser.close();});

Comment: @EdiImanto, even after changing browser is afterAll(async()=>{ await browser.close();});  still getting the same issue

Comment: I think you should provide more detailed code than just a section like above.

Also try to click the element within `await elementHandle.evaluate( node => node.click() )`

Comment: @EdiImanto, i have updated the code to match the scenario and tried $$eval within the test and function also.  Works in the test but does not work when the code is in function.

Comment: I've add another answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put await in the function calling, like this.

```
const CommFun = require('./commonfunction');
    test('Verify "question"',async() => {
    await CommFun.ToggleButton("question","//div[@role=\'tabpanel\']/div/div/div/div/div")
    },30000);
```

Comment: so simple but effective,  my code worked now.  Thanks.  I will change the question so others can also know about it

Comment: my pleasure :D .

Answer (score 0):

As I saw in your code above, you made a typo in your variable name `const QuestionLableXpath`. Then you used the correct name `QuestionLabelXpath`, so they didn't match. Try fixing the name and see what the result looks like.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, it was my typo mistake while creating this question, corrected now.  In my actual testing i am passing this as parameter to the function.  The code fails at this click operation.